# Dokuwiki Plugin to List and Link to Directory

Tags: dokuwiki

I use Dokuwiki to keep all my personal stuff straight. One of the things I'd really like to be able to do is to scan bills, statements and stuff through a scanner, and dump the PDF into a directory. Then have a dokuwiki page that lists the contents of that directory with a link to the PDF. The point is that I don't have to edit the wiki page, just the fact the file is added to the directory should be enough to get it listed. Filename would be enough for meta data.

That seems a useful plugin in lots of contexts, but I have looked through the gigantic number of dokuwiki plugins and can't see anything.

Anyone know of something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are simple tools such as the "[Directory Listing Syntax PlugIn](http://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:dirlisting)" (that page lists a couple of similar plugins).

There is also [this](http://www.foosel.org/snippets/dokuwiki/filelist) along similar lines.

Comment: No worries, it would be great if you came back and left your own answer when you've got things set up.